# Aggregate debit and credit amounts with different dates on a daily basis and group by accounts

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, transactions

I have a table with debit amounts, credit amounts, debit date, credit date and account ids. Where ever there is a debit amount entry, the credit amount would be null and vice versa. I need to have the sum of debits and credits for each day.

| id | Debit_date | Debit_amount | Credit_date | Credit_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10-21 | 20000 | NA | NA |
| 1 | NA | NA | 2018-10-21 | 50000 |
| 2 | 2019-1-2 | 10000 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 2019-1-3 | 20000 | NA | NA |
| 4 | NA | NA | 2019-1-4 | 30000 |
| 1 | 2019-1-5 | 1000 | NA | NA |

I need to get the output below:

| id | Trans_date | Total_debit | Total_credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10-21 | 20000 | 50000 |
| 1 | 2019-1-5 | 1000 | NA |
| 2 | 2019-1-2 | 30000 | NA |
| 4 | 2019-1-4 | NA | 30000 |

I tried the following code:

```
df_db = df %>%  group_by(id,debit_date) %>% summarise(total_debit=sum(debit_amount))
df_cr = df %>%  group_by(id,credit_date) %>% summarise(total_credit=sum(credit_amount))
```

I then proceed to join these two dataframes but it just blows it up since i have millions of transactions. Can anyone please guide me on how to get the data in the output above. Would really appreciate.

Comment: Is the data originally in a database? I'm wondering why you tagged this with [tag:sql].

Comment: Yes it is part of a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `coalesce` to group by date:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id, Trans_date = coalesce(Debit_date, Credit_date)) %>% 
  summarise(Total_debit = sum(Debit_amount, na.rm = T),
            Total_credit = sum(Credit_amount, na.rm = T))

     id Trans_date Total_debit Total_credit
1     1 2018-10-21       20000        50000
2     1 2019-1-5          1000            0
3     2 2019-1-2         30000            0
4     4 2019-1-4             0        30000
```

data (I tweaked `Date` of the fifth row to match expected output)

```r
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L), Debit_date = c("2018-10-21", 
NA, "2019-1-2", "2019-1-2", NA, "2019-1-5"), Debit_amount = c(20000L, 
NA, 10000L, 20000L, NA, 1000L), Credit_date = c(NA, "2018-10-21", 
NA, NA, "2019-1-4", NA), Credit_amount = c(NA, 50000L, NA, NA, 
30000L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```